# VB.NET WMI Win32_Printer not returning locally added network shared printers

Tags: vb.net, printing, wmi, network-printers

I'm having a problem with this code querying installed/added printers.

If I put \.\root\CIMV2\ it works and lists locally added printers and locally added network printers.

If I put in a computername it only lists the locally added printers, but none of the shared network printers that are added to the machine. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
Private Sub DoShowPrinters(Computer)
    Try
        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("\\" & Computer & "\root\CIMV2", "SELECT DeviceID FROM Win32_Printer")
        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(queryObj("DeviceID").ToString())
        Next
    Catch err As ManagementException
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for printer data: " & err.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want list the printers installed on the machine the app is installed or a list of printers installed on a remote pc (determined by the computer parameter)?

Comment: A remote PC in our domain